# Is there a function in Python similar to Matlab's deconvblind?

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, convolution, deconvolution

I'm working on blind deconvoltuion.

In iterating L2norm reguralization, I want to update the PSF at the same time, and when I looked it up, I found a function called [`deconvblind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/deconvblind.html) in Matlab:

> l[J,PSF] = deconvblind(I,INITPSF) deconvolves image I using the maximum likelihood algorithm,
> returning both the deblurred image, J, and a restored point-spread function, PSF.
> The input array, I, and your initial guess at the PSF, INITPSF, can be numeric arrays or cell arrays.
> (Use cell arrays when you want to be able to perform additional
> deconvolutions that start where your initial deconvolution finished.
> See Resuming Deconvolution for more information.)
> The restored PSF is a positive array that is the same size as INITPSF, normalized so its sum adds up to 1.

Is there a function similar to `deconvblind` in Python?

Comment: If you have MATLAB at hand, you can use [MATLAB engine for Python](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html). I just used it specifically for this function, works without any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can implement blind deconvolution in python with the **Richardson Lucy** algorithm:

Iterative updation steps for **Blind Deblurring** (as proposed in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6I9t.png), [4](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1206/1206.3594.pdf)), with **unknown** PSF H, corrupted image **X** and restored image **S** are shown in the below equation:

[image]

The following code shows my implementation of the iterative Bayesian blind deconvolution algorithm proposed in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2SuP.gif), mostly with frequency domain operations (as opposed to spatial domain implementation as in [3](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.richardson_lucy)). It is similar to the non-blind implementation as in [3](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.richardson_lucy), only we need to estimate the unknown blur PSF at each iteration (starting with a random PSF), assumed to be known in [3](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.richardson_lucy).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve

def richardson_lucy_blind(image, psf, original, num_iter=50):    
    im_deconv = np.full(image.shape, 0.1, dtype='float')    # init output
    for i in range(num_iter):
        psf_mirror = np.flip(psf)
        conv = fftconvolve(im_deconv, psf, mode='same')
        relative_blur = image / conv
        im_deconv *= fftconvolve(relative_blur, psf_mirror, mode='same')
        im_deconv_mirror = np.flip(im_deconv)
        psf *= fftconvolve(relative_blur, im_deconv_mirror, mode='same')    
    return im_deconv
```

The next animation shows image restoration with non-blind and blind versions of the RL algorithm, respectively.

[image]
**References:**

1. https://courses.cs.duke.edu/cps258/fall06/references/Nonnegative-iteration/Richardson-alg.pdf
2. https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.richardson_lucy
3. https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1206/1206.3594.pdf

Comment: how can apply this to signal data,?

Comment: nice work! in the matlab implementation is possible to give a mask that specifies which pixels in the input image I are considered in the restoration (https://it.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/deconvblind.html#d123e53865) how is possible to do that editing your implementation ?

Comment: Fish et. al 95's simple adaptation of Hadley's method should be preferred as it has better convergence properties.

Additionally, `original` is unused in your code and the original image is a better initial guess for the ground truth.